# Cómo puedo crear mas de dos activitys sin que se cree una aplicacion en el celular por cada activity?

Tags: java, android, activity

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Documento_identidad"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".c_c"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".c_e"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".t_i"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".terminosycondiciones"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Buen día, en los siguientes links te incluyo la documentación de Android: 1. [Iniciar otra activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity?hl=es-419)
2. [Lanzar un segundo Activity desde otro Activity](https://www.movilzona.es/tutoriales/android/desarrollo/curso-de-desarrollo-android-tema-11-android-studio-lanzar-un-segundo-activity-desde-otro-activity/) Considero que en ellos encontrarás mejores explicaciones que las que yo te puedo dar. Te serán más útiles.

Comment: Puedes abrir cualquier cantidad de activities, agrega las clases, registralas en tu AndroidManifest.xml y corrige el contexto definido en el intent, por ejemplo si esta clase activity se llama "MainActivity" sería : Intent cc = new Intent(MainActiivity,this, c_c.class); agregué respuesta.

Comment: hmm de ninguna de las dos formas deja de crearme una app por cada activity

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar tu AndroidManifest.xml? tal vez ahí este el problema.

Comment: No se si lo puedas entender, es la única forma que puedo subirlo

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y subirlo.

Comment: Ya esta el manifest

Comment: Gracias por agregar tu AndroidManifest.xml @Laura2604, solo la Activity que inicia la aplicación debe tener el intent-filter, revisa mi actualización.

Comment: @Laura2604 el intent-filter definido únicamente debe ser para la Activity que inicia la aplicación, elimina el intent-filter de las demás Activity

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, se solucionó quitando el intent. Es que soy nueva en esto. Mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

#### Actualización:

Al ver tu AndroidManifest.xml se puede ver que hay otro problema de configuración, en el cual todas tus Activity tienen definido el intent-filter para la Activity principal

**Debes eliminar el siguiente intent-filter de la activity que no sea la inicial**:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

esto debe solucionar el problema:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Documento_identidad"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".c_c"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">        
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".c_e"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".t_i"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".terminosycondiciones"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

En tu aplicación puedes crear cualquier cantidad de Activities, para que puedas usarlas en tu aplicación **es importante crear las clases y registrarlas en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`**:

```
    ...
    ...
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Declara tus activity -->
    <activity android:name=".OtraActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".c_c"/>
    <activity android:name=".c_e"/>
    <activity android:name=".t_i"/>
    ...
    ...
```

al declararlas puedes hacer uso de ellas, por ejemplo en tu caso en el cual deseas abrirlas mediante un `Intent` desde la `Activity` principal.

Recuerda también que para abrir la Activity desde un método debes asignar correctamente el contexto, en este caso **esto es incorrecto**:

```
 Intent cc = new Intent(this, c_c.class);
 startActivity(cc);
```

**las opciones correctas son** usando la referencia de la `Activity`, por ejemplo si tu activity desde donde deseas abrir la `Activity` es llamada `MainActivity` :

```
 Intent cc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, c_c.class);
 startActivity(cc);
```

o usar `getApplicationContext()` si realizas el `Intent` desde una `Activity`:

```
 Intent cc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), c_c.class);
 startActivity(cc);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias..

Answer (score 0):

el problema se encuentra en que tienes tus otros activitys como main y launcher, elimina los intent-filter de tus activitys que no seran el activity principal, es lo que esta generando un icono de tu aplicacion por cada activity del proyecto

android.intent.action.MAIN: La acción es el principal punto de entrada de la aplicación.

android.intent.category.LAUNCHER: Dice que el punto de entrada debe aparecer en el iniciador de aplicaciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

@Laura2604 por favor quita los intent filter del manifest. Solo un activity debería ser el punto de entrada de tu app, y el único que tenga esta configuración.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>.
```

Las demás activities no!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias..

Comment: Si te ha sido de ayuda la respuesta, marcalá como aceptada @Laura2604